# Application crashes with "... stopped working" when brought to foreground

Tags: c#, winforms, crash

I recently got the request to fix a bug in a tool which was created by a co-worker which has left the company.

This tool is basically a WinForms-application based on .NET-Framework 4. It works fine in general but the following situation will lead to random crashes:

**If the program is in the background (doesn't have the focus) and is brought to the foreground (focused / activated) by the user after a while, it crashes with the message  "ToolName has stopped working".**

ToolName is replaced with "vshost.exe" if it's executed under a debugger. *There is no additional error message displayed*. I don't know which line of the code causes the error.

Some additional information:

- If I try to force this error by activating the window, activate another Window (for example Outlook), then activate the window of my tool again, this will rarely crash the tool (there must be some other leverage).
- The MainForm has no assigned event-handlers except *Form_Load* and *Form_SizeChanged*
- The application uses the WeifenLuo-Docking-Library and ZedGraph-Library.
- I have the impression that this error appears only if the application runned for a while.
- The crash appears at least on two computers which run Windows 7 x64. (I haven't tried any other so far)
- I can't attach a debbuger to the crashing process (neither Visual Studio 2010 nor 2013 will work!). I get the message

*"The current debugger is configured to debug code that uses Microsoft .NET Framework v 1.0, 1.1, or 2.0. An unhandled exception is being thrown from .NET Framework v4.0 code."*

I tried to obtain more information about the crash by adding global exception handlers which should create a MessageBox with the stack-trace but they don't fire:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
  AppDomain currentDomain = default(AppDomain);
  currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

  currentDomain.UnhandledException += GlobalUnhandledExceptionHandler;
  System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += GlobalThreadExceptionHandler;

  // ...
}

private static void GlobalUnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  Exception ex = default(Exception);
  ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;

  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
}

private static void GlobalThreadExceptionHandler(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  Exception ex = default(Exception);
  ex = e.Exception;

  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

In my desparation I added a try-catch-Block around Application.Run which won't fire as well:

```
try
{
   Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got rid of the crashes:

The application created an instance of a 3rd-party COM-Object implemented in a native language. This instance was created in a thread (propably to avoid a *Loader Lock*-Error which would appear if created on the main thread).

In the event log (found in the control panel) there where more information about the crash. There was a hint to the name of the DLL which caused the crash (Thanks to Tom for the tip!).

I changed the creation of the COM-object from early binding (via dynamic and Activator.CreateInstance()) to late-binding (I added a reference to the COM-object in Visual Studio). This allows me to create an instance of the COM-object on the main thread during startup.

I didn't experienced any crashes since then.

Answer (score 5):

When I run into issues like this, I usually start with the Event Viewer. Windows will log application crashes to the Event Viewer, even if they are silent. Sometimes, it is able to spit out a stack trace which can make things even easier. From my experience, the application is silently crashing because it is trying to load some dependency that is missing and it is getting a TypeInitializationException.

It is hard for me to tell you what the root cause without known more information about the application. Is the application loading any 3rd party libraries? Any custom control drawing happening in the application? I believe .NET lazy loads types. If a type isn't needed until the application tries to draw itself, then it may not get loaded until the application is first shown. At that point, if the type is missing the application will crash. Does the app start minimized? Are the crashes random or consistent? Meaning, if you show the application on start up, does it work? Or does it ALWAYS crash when you first display the app?

What version of Visual Studio are you using? Is your project file set to .NET 4? You can select what code type to attach with when you attach to a process. In the Attach to Process dialog, press "Select" to the right of Attach to (default should be Automatic: Native code). Then select the desired code type. This option is in the same place for VS 2010 and 2013.

Comment: I've tried Visual Studio 2010 and 2013. The project-file is set to .NET 4. The applicationen uses the third-party libraries mention in the question (WeifenLuo-Docking and ZedGraph-Lib). The application is starting regular, not minimized. There is no CustomDrawing. It never crashes at the first display of the app, only if it was minimized and restored (at least!) once.

Comment: There are some information regarding the crash in the event-log (thanks for the tip). It says there is some Exception " 0xc0000005" in an external native DLL I forgot to mention. Unfortunately I don't have access to the source code of it. Regardless of the settings Visual Studio don't let me debug the crashing app. There is only message that says "Can't connect to the crashing application" accordingly.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. Are you able to extract out the 3rd party libraries one at a time to see if one of those is the culprit? I realize this means you will need to remove some functionality, but this will help you eliminate some possibilities.

Usually the Event Viewer will log 2 items for a .NET crash, one is tagged as an error and the other as information. Check both of them out for relevant information (stack trace, exception type, dll causing an issue, etc)